# Can I display Google+ Feeds on a web site

Tags: social-networking, google-plus

Can I display Google+ Feeds on a web site similar to how Facebook and Twitter allow you to have a feed plugin?

I'd like my web site to display feeds from all 3 of these social networks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be what you're looking for, but the closest thing to what you're asking for is listing the public data for a specific user on Google+ or searching public posts on Google+.

The public data (read) API is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities

You can see it in action through the APIs explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=%252BGusClass&collection=public&_h=1&

You can download the latest version of the client libraries for most programming languages from here:

https://developers.google.com/+/downloads

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I'd have to take the json return, and format that how I want to. There's no premade formats available?

Comment: The APIs return JSON from the Google endpoints.  However, there are client libraries for most programming languages that will convert the JSON into native objects for those languages.  Adding a link in the answer.